# Use the linear approximation of $f$ at $(1,0)$ to approximate $f(1.1, 0.1)$ where $f(x,y) = xe^{xy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$L(x,y)$ is the linear approximation for $f(x,y)$ near $(x_0,y_0)$

$$L(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

I found $f_x(x,y) = e^{xy} + xye^{xy}$ and $f_y(x,y) = x^2 e^{xy}$

I plugged in $(1.1,0.1)$ in the formula but there's still the variable $x$, so how do I get a complete value?

What I did:

f(x,y) ~ f(1.1,0.1) + e^[(1.1)(0.1)] + (1.1)(0.1)e^[(1.1)(0.1)] (x-1.1)+(1.1)e^[(1.1)(0.1)] (y-0.1)

Note, the answer to the approximation is $1$.

Comment: Why do you still have $x$ there if you plugged in a value for $x$?

Comment: Show your work. What did you plug in and what did you get?

Comment: Compare $$f_x(x_0,y_0)\qquad f_y(x_0,y_0)$$ with "I plugged in $(1.1,0.1)$ in the formula". One is supposed to plug in $(x_0,y_0)$. In your case, this is $(1,0)$ hence $$f_x(x_0,y_0)=f_y(x_0,y_0)=1$$

Comment: Yes, i plugged in 1.1 for x0 and 0.1 for y0, i'm unsure on the values of x and y though?

Comment: "Yes, i plugged in 1.1 for x0 and 0.1 for y0" And you should not have, as I explained in my comment. Did you read it?

Comment: Obviously I read it. So you're saying i have to plug it in the partial derivatives and we get 1? Not the linear approximation formula?

Answer (score 2):

You are approximating at $(x,y) = (1,0)$, so $(x_0,y_0)=(1,0)$.

As you rightly say:
$$L(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

Since $f(x,y) = x\mathrm e^{xy}$, it follows that $f_x(x,y) = (1+xy)\mathrm e^{xy}$ and $f_y(x,y) = x^2\mathrm e^{xy}$.

Putting $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0) = (1,0)$ gives $f(1,0)=1$, $f_x(1,0)=1$ and $f_y(1,0)=1$, and so
$$L(x,y) = 1 + 1(x-1) + 1(y-0) \ \ \equiv \ \ \ x+y$$

For any $(x,y)$ close to $(1,0)$ we can say that $f(x,y) \approx L(x,y)$.

If $(x,y)=(1.1,0.1)$ then $f(1.1,0.1) \approx L(1.1,0.1)$, i.e.

$$1.1\mathrm e^{1.1\times 0.1} \approx 1.1+0.1$$

Using a computer to evaluate $1.1\mathrm e^{1.1\times 0.1}$ gives around $1.22791$, while $1.1+0.1 = 1.2$.

The percentage error is given by

$$100 \times\left(\frac{\mathbb{actual}-\mathrm{estimate}}{\mathbb{actual}}\right) \ \ = \ \ 2.27 \%$$